# How can I have fail2ban log to an external syslog server?

Tags: syslog, fail2ban

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 web server (running Webmin). I also have [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) running on a separate server on my LAN.

I'd like to have fail2ban log itself to `/var/log/fail2ban.log` **as well as** my external syslog server, but I'm not sure how to do this.

In the fail2ban config file, there's an option to change `logtarget=/var/log/fail2ban.log` to `logtarget = SYSLOG`, but I'm not sure how to get those outputs over to the other server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Ubuntu uses rsyslog by default. Check out the "imfile" options to read your fail2ban log and set up forwarding.

See a similar question here for details.  [How to forward specific log file outside of /var/log with rsyslog to remote server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/396136/how-to-forward-specific-log-file-outside-of-var-log-with-rsyslog-to-remote-serv)