# Can we configure Apache to send logs directly to a log analysis system?

Tags: apache-2.4, logging

I want to configure Apache to send access logs to a log analysis system so is it possible to do it by configuring Apache or I have to use a Syslog tool to send logs.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of having syslog handling the Apache logs, Apache can very well send its logging immediately to syslog, as explained eg. [Apache config syslog](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS42VS_DSM/com.ibm.dsm.doc/t_DSM_guide_apache_cfg_syslog.html)

This is sufficient:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -t httpd -p <facility>.<priority>" <log format name>
```

You may need configuring syslog, if the standard treatment of these messages is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention a specific log analysis software i think you want to accomplish this via the syslog protocol. Therefore, you need to do the following on your syslog Client (apache webserver).

1. Create a ConfigFile under /etc/rsyslog.d/apache_access.log.conf

For access.log:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/log/apache2/access.log
$InputFileTag apache_access:
$InputFileStateFile stat-apache-access
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputRunFileMonitor
$InputFilePollInterval 10
local3.* @@ip-analysis-system:<portnumber-ip-analysis-system>
```

For error.log

```
/etc/rsyslog.conf
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFileName /var/log/apache2/error.log
$InputFileTag apache_error:
$InputFileStateFile stat-apache-error
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputFileFacility local3
$InputRunFileMonitor
$InputFilePollInterval 10
local3.* @@ip-analysis-system:<portnumber-ip-analysis-system>
```

2. Restart syslog with:

   systemctl restart rsyslog

   Now all data from the local3 facility is send to your analysis-server.

By the way: I think your question is a duplicate. Look at the link below.

> [How to forward specific log file outside of /var/log with rsyslog to remote server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/396136/how-to-forward-specific-log-file-outside-of-var-log-with-rsyslog-to-remote-serv)